# Firebase Auth authStateListener is not firing following signInAnonymously

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

My Firebase Auth listener fires once, but not subsequently.

Some example code in Kotlin/Android:

```
val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
auth.addAuthStateListener { Log.v("tabXd", "onAuthStateChanged: id=${it.uid}") }

val thread = HandlerThread("h1").apply { start() }
val handler = Handler(thread.looper)
handler.post {
    Log.v("tabId", "auth1=${auth.uid}")
    auth.signOut()
    Thread.sleep(2000L)
    Log.v("tabId", "auth2=${auth.uid}")
    auth.signInAnonymously()
    Thread.sleep(5000L)
    Log.v("tabId", "auth3=${auth.uid}")
}
```

It's a fairly brutal example (the Handler exists just to make sure this isn't a threading problem) but what I expect is this:

```
onAuthStateChanged: id=[ID of user who was logged in previously]
auth1=[ID of user who was logged in previously]
onAuthStateChanged: id=null
auth2=null
onAuthStateChanged: id=[new user ID]
auth3=[new user ID]
```

and what I get is this:

```
auth1=tX9pnhsXwlb9OJ4aDyF5jRG441L2
onAuthStateChanged: id=null
onAuthStateChanged: id=null
auth2=null
auth3=P4EIL2TAubYaY0P0miGdyLpVB5u1
```

The specific problem is that the auth state change listener is never called to reflect the new user following the `signInAnonymously()` call.

I think it should also be called once at the beginning, too, to reflect the current state, but I could be wrong.

Is the callback to the auth state listener perhaps being blocked (thread deadlock) for some reason? My understanding is that it's called on the main thread, and the use of the handler there is to demonstrate that nothing *should* be using the main thread.